# Use Sharepoint Designer with Sharepoint Online and ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, adfs

is there a way to use Sharepoint Designer 2013 with Sharepoint online (Office 365) with ADFS in place? I've downloaded SPD 2013 but everytime that I tried to open a site I don't get the ADFS prompt. Without logging thru ADFS I cannot get to my site, has anyone run into this problem? Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Did you install SPD services pack 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue normally get fixed with installing the [SharePoint Designer Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2817441/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-designer-2013-service-pack-1-sp1).  Workflows related issues are also resolved by installing this.

Comment: I have SP1 installed, but while logging in SP designer do not redirect me to my federated idp for logging in. I am asked to enter password in microsoft login screen itself.  Any ideas?